# Add x86 bit code into a dll which is x64 bit

Tags: c++, dll, discord

I was making a custom discord rich presence, which I want to add into a dll. I can put the files into my dll, but that dll is x64 and it needs to be because the target where the dll is being injected into is an x64 game.
The discord rich presence code is x86.
I dont know how I could make it work.

Comment: x86 is all but history nowadays. I would contact Discord and ask for a x64 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t mix 32- and 64-bit code in the same binary.

You can implement your functionality in a separate executable and use some inter-process communication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/interprocess-communication?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Okay. It really is just a couple variables that I need to use in my x86 program. thanks i will try this

Comment: @YoooOoOoOOOOOo please see the link I've added to the answer